# Why do my renders look Flat?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am unfamiliar with this version so it might be a setting error but when I try to render my test model it goes from 3D to flat.  Is there something wrong with my shading?

[image]

Comment: How does your material setup look like, can you add a screenshot? Also when you're saying that you're unfamiliar with "this version", you mean the version of Blender? What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see your node setup, to know which rendering engine you're using (Eevee, Cycles, or Blender Render if you're using 2.79 or earlier) and which version of Blender you are using.

However, I attempted to reproduce your issue using an approximately similar shape and this is what I found:

A rough approximation of your flat rendered shape.
[image]
A jury-rigged version of your shading here.
[image]
Node setup for this shading.
[image]

If this is what your node setup looks like, this is **incorrect**. You should add a **Shader** node first, connect it to the Surface input of the Material Output node, and add your to that Shader node, as shown below.

[image]
Result of above node setup.
[image]

I hope that this helps, but more details will help illuminate the problem!

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot sorry for the missing details and late response.